# How do I join a query that uses a top 1 clause to a query that uses aggregate functions?

Tags: sql

I have a query that uses a TOP 1 clause (query2) that I want to join to another query that uses aggregate functions, but I'm not sure how to do it.

I'd like a resulting query that looks something like this:

```
"select Count(*), Avg(AmtSpent), TOP 1 (Outlet_Code)...."
```

Please kindly advise. Thanks.

Query 1:

```
select Count(*), Avg(AmtSpent) from Transact Where CardNo In
(Select CardNo from Card where MemberID = 'Mem003')
```

Query 2:

```
select TOP 1 (Outlet_Code) from Transact where CardNo In
(Select CardNo from Card where MemberID = 'Mem003')
group by Outlet_Code
Order by count(Outlet_Code) desc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this, as long as each subquery is only returning one row, which looks to be the case because one of your queries is selecting top 1, and the other has no group by clause.  This works in SQL Server 2008.

```
select TransactCount, TransactAvg, OutletCode
from
(

    select TOP 1 (Outlet_Code) as OutletCode 
    from Transact where CardNo In
    (Select CardNo from Card where MemberID = 'Mem003')
    group by Outlet_Code
    Order by count(Outlet_Code) desc


) rsOutletCode
cross join
(

    select Count(*) as TransactCount, Avg(AmtSpent) as TransactAvg
    from Transact 
    Where CardNo In
    (Select CardNo from Card where MemberID = 'Mem003')

) rsTransact
```

Answer (score 2):

Do the first query and the apply the other:

```
-- Temp tables for demo
CREATE TABLE #Transact (
    ID  INT PRIMARY KEY,
    AmtSpent NUMERIC(18,2),
    CardNo INT,
    Outlet_Code VARCHAR(10)
)

CREATE TABLE #Card (
    CardNo INT PRIMARY KEY,
    MemberID VARCHAR(10)
)

-- Some mock values
INSERT #Card VALUES (1, 'Mem001')
INSERT #Card VALUES (2, 'Mem002')
INSERT #Card VALUES (3, 'Mem003')
INSERT #Card VALUES (4, 'Mem004')
INSERT #Card VALUES (5, 'Mem005')
INSERT #Card VALUES (6, 'Mem006')
INSERT #Card VALUES (7, 'Mem007')
INSERT #Card VALUES (8, 'Mem008')
INSERT #Card VALUES (9, 'Mem009')

INSERT #Transact VALUES (1, 100.0, 1, 'Outlet 1')
INSERT #Transact VALUES (2, 200.0, 1, 'Outlet 2')
INSERT #Transact VALUES (3, 300.0, 2, 'Outlet 3')
INSERT #Transact VALUES (4, 400.0, 2, 'Outlet 4')
INSERT #Transact VALUES (5, 500.0, 3, 'Outlet 5')
INSERT #Transact VALUES (6, 600.0, 8, 'Outlet 6')
INSERT #Transact VALUES (7, 700.0, 9, 'Outlet 7')

DECLARE @MemberID VARCHAR(10)

SET @MemberID = 'Mem002'

-- The query
SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS Count,
    AVG(T.AmtSpent) AS Average,
    _T.Outlet_Code
FROM
    #Transact T

    INNER JOIN #Card C ON
    T.CardNo = C.CardNo

    OUTER APPLY (
        SELECT
            TOP 1 Outlet_Code
        FROM
            #Transact _T

            INNER JOIN #Card C ON
            _T.CardNo = C.CardNo
        WHERE
            C.MemberID = @MemberID
        GROUP BY
            Outlet_Code
    ) AS _T
WHERE
    C.MemberID = @MemberID
GROUP BY
    _T.Outlet_Code

-- Clean up mock stuff
DROP TABLE #Card
DROP TABLE #Transact
```